# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: .constants.json

Tags: python, pyinstaller, openpyxl

I have coded a python script involving excel sheet manipulation using `openpyxl`. Script is running fine using python interpreter. Once I have made single windows executable using `pyinstaller` and running the program, its throwing error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\....\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI31842\\.constants.json'
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

You might need to tell PyInstaller to include this file:

Put a file `hook-openpyxl.py` in the directory from where you run pyinstaller:

```
# hook-openpyxl.py

from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files

datas = collect_data_files('openpyxl')
```

Then run pyinstaller as:

```
pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=. yourscriptname.py
```

Comment: Did this work for anyone? I was using cx_freeze, but since they didn't want to fix the issue, I thought it would be better to switch to pyinstaller instead. Any luck? 
- I am using python 3.5

Comment: Just tried it, and it didn't work: File "c:\users\sebastian\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\jinja2\asyncsupport.py", line 35
    yield event
              ^
SyntaxError: 'yield' inside async function

Answer (score 0):

I am using Openpyxl version 2.5.12
Python 3.7
and Pyinstaller version 3.4

I am able to compile the exe without error. 
The command I am using is as follows:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon ABC.ico "..\\src\\src_file.py"
```