# script works in ide but with pyinstaller export to excel with openpyxl doesnt work

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, openpyxl

I have build a program which fully work in the IDE but when I build an .EXE from it with pyinstaller the program works only 90%. The last part of the program should export the data from the rest of the program to an Excelfile on the desktop (made with openpyxl).

My program used to work fine when I made a .EXE on windows 8. I upgraded my pc to windows 10 and made changes to the code and want to remake the .EXE but now it won't work (no new modules used).

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: openpyxl does not support PyInstaller. Apparently there is a workaround which you can **search** for.

Comment: Thanks this is true I found a solution that worked for me at: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36076319/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-constants-json/40225481#40225481)

Comment: @CharlieClark Since I am using cx_freeze, do you know whether there is workaround for cx_freeze. It's the exact same issue apart from the software.